# ActiveMQ Artemis clusterd env - retained messages are not accurate after the broker restarts

Tags: restart, retain, messagebroker, activemq-artemis

What is the behavior when a new client connects to a cluster with respect to retained messages? Will it get the retained messages received by all the nodes in the cluster?

Comment: Please narrow your question down. You've asked multiple distinct questions here which is not really how Stack Overflow is designed to work.

Comment: @JustinBertram I have edited it to only one question. Thanks